# How to count expected number of paterns?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, probability

Member of parliament can vote or can be absent during voting. Let assume:

If, for a given MP, there is a pattern present-absent-present (`010`) in consecutive voting, this absence is strategic - MP does not want to reveal his preferences.

For each MPs I have a data in the format:

```
    00011001000101_00001000_10_011_00000
```

Where `0` means presence of MP during voting, `1` - absence. `_` means there was a  interruption (ie. coffee break, night etc.) between voting.

I can count probability of absence of MP - it is number of all absences divided by a number of all votings.

Assuming absences are independent, and probability for one absence is known (computed as above), how can I count expected number of `010` patterns in data?

For above data, I want to do it this way:

```
    p=9/(23+9)=0.28125 - probability of absence
    (1-p)*p*(1-p) = 0.1453 - probability of 010 pattern
    number of all possible length 3 patterns in given data:
    (14-2)+(8-2)+(2-2)+(3-2)+(5-2) = 22
    so the expected number of 010 pattern is 22*0.1453 == 3.2
```

is my reasoning OK?

How can I test - based on expected and real numbers of `010` patterns -  if this is only by chance or not?